# Modal dialog with a horizontal form, side by side groups

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm attempting to render, side by side, form elements within a bootstrap modal dialog. Reason for this is that they're for all intents and purposes the same options, just representing options for different items and the current way it renders for users is basically:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><!--Option Group 1--></td>
    <td><!--Option Group 2--></td>
    <td><!--Option Group 3--></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So using the modal dialog example in the Bootstrap 3 documentation combined with the form-horizontal exampl in the Bootstrap 3 documentation plus some use of span to attempt to do a 50% width for each (and hopefully left-to-right tiling of the sections), I came out with:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="addLabel">Title of Dialog</h4>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputUser" class="col-sm-1 control-label">User</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUser" value="" disabled="disabled">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputUser" class="col-sm-1 control-label">User</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputUser" value="" disabled="disabled">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Request</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3zeMh/

The problem is that somewhere along the way, it is forcing each item to go new line so I have two "forms" that are 50% of the parent width (intentional) that are rendered vertically (not intentional). How can I make the two render side by side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="span6">
```

should be

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
```

2 times.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3zeMh/4

It needs a little further cleanup, but that's the primary issue. Here's one possible refinement: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3zeMh/6

I'd probably make the labels wider and keep everything block for mobile, though.

Comment: You're completely right. Was going off memory on the span6 bit and forgot the change to col-sm-6 for bootstrap 3. Even with that, it wouldn't render side by side but with your fiddle, worked fine.